# DB2 z/OS: Create function failed with SQLCODE = -104

Tags: db2

Below create function statement works fine on DB2 LUW, but failed on DB2 V9.1 for z/OS.

```
CREATE FUNCTION  PLAT_FN_GASN  (
 OBJID CHARACTER(18) )
  RETURNS CHARACTER(18) 
  LANGUAGE SQL 
  READS SQL 
  DATA DETERMINISTIC 
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
  RETURN SELECT SRCOBJID
  FROM PLAT_V_RELATIONSHIPS AS R2
  WHERE RELTYPENAME = 'ApplyTaskRefOutputSpec' AND MODELNAME = 'MiningTask'
    AND TGTOBJID = (SELECT SRCOBJID
              FROM PLAT_V_RELATIONSHIPS AS R1
              WHERE RELTYPENAME = 'ApplyOutputHasContentItems' AND MODELNAME = 'MiningTask'
               AND TGTOBJID = OBJID)
```

Error message is:

```
ILLEGAL SYMBOL "SRCOBJID". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: SOURCE PARAMETER STOP INHERIT RETURNS CALLED ALLOW CONTAINS. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.53.71
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the SQL statement. Can someone give me a clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason is DB2 for z/OS V9 doesn't support scalar select in RETURN for an SQL UDF. The syntax is correct although. DB2 for z/OS V10 should support this.

Thanks.